# ZXing 2D barcode decoding: UTF-8 characters not decoded properly

Tags: java, utf-8, barcode, zxing

I'm trying to use ZXing to read 2D barcodes and it mostly works fine, except it doesn't really recognize some UTF-8 characters like č and ć. I'm using this code to set the encoding:

```
MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
Hashtable hints = new Hashtable();
hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");  
reader.setHints(hints);
result = reader.decode(bitmap);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: I also tried calling the overload for decode which takes hints, but the result was the same.

Comment: Which barcode type you are talking about? Not all 2D codes support utf-8. The decoding result would be helpful also. And as there might be an error in the way you generated the barcode, it would help if you would show an example barcode.

Comment: @tobitobs: PDF417. The result gives me "Ä " instead of "Č", for example. It's probably valid because I didn't generate the barcode - I'm trying to scan official standardized payment forms.

Comment: Without barcode example this is just a guessing game, my guess it is a ISO-8859-1(5) encoded barcode.

Comment: @tobitobs: Try googling "hub3a obrazac" and you should see a lot of examples. The documents say that the encoding is UTF-8, but I'll try the ones you suggested, just to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I was creating my bitmap the wrong way. This worked:

```
MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);

BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
    new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(
            ImageIO.read(fis))));

Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);

String originalText = result.getText();
byte[] bytes = originalText.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
String outputText = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This is sort of cheating... I mean, you are just "filtering" out the characters that aren't understood by the encoding, forcing the components dependency back into your own code... AUCH.